# Python Post Need help creating post payload

Tags: python, json, post

I will admit I'm fairly new to Python and JSON...

There is an API
.../apix
That requires JSON post payload to look exactly like this (INCLUDING the outer brackets [] and inner curtly brackets {}):

```
[ 
 {
     "dest":2,
     "ciRelationType":3
  }
]
```

How do I build this and send via post?

tried this:

```
post_payload = {[{"dest":2,"ciRelationType":3}]}
```

and this:

```
post_payload = {"dest":2,"ciRelationType":3}
```

then this:
`rpost = requests.post(url=post_url, headers=reqHeaders, data=post_payload)` or this

```
rpost = requests.post(url=post_url, headers=reqHeaders, data=json.dumps(post_payload))
```

and usually get: unhashable list errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
rpost = requests.post(url=post_url, headers=reqHeaders, json=[{"dest":2,"ciRelationType":3}])
```

as you can pass json body directly in key name 'json' in python requests lib

or

```
post_payload = [{"dest":2,"ciRelationType":3}] 
rpost = requests.post(url=post_url, headers=reqHeaders, data=json.dumps(post_payload))
```